# tell compass to stop watching a folder - beginner stuff

Tags: rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I'm starting to read about sass and scss and am experimenting with installing compass to compile my css.

I know I can use the command

```
compass watch
```

to automatically compile css when sass files are modified

but how do I tell compass to stop watching a folder if I want to stop this behavior

what is actually happening here, am I adding more processes running in the background on my system?

thanks for your patience with my beginner questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't run the compass command and it won't watch the directory. To run it in the first place you need to open a terminal/command prompt and type:

```
compass watch DIR
```

That starts a process in your terminal/command prompt. To stop it you can interrupt it (Ctrl->C on *nix).